# How to disable a specific day in Datepicker ? (Gravity Forms)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, datepicker

I'm using the Gravity Forms plugin on WordPress, which includes jQuery's datepicker. In one of my form, I defined a minDate and a maxDate but within this array of dates, I need to disable one specific day (which is Sunday, April 23).

I found the way to disable the whole weekend with the noWeekend function but the thing is: I need to keep Saturday 22 available !

Here's the code I'm using right now :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
gform.addFilter( 'gform_datepicker_options_pre_init', function( optionsObj, formId, fieldId ) {
    if ( formId == 2 && fieldId == 4 ) {
    optionsObj.minDate = '17/04/2017';
    optionsObj.maxDate = '29/04/2017';
}

return optionsObj;
} );
</script>
```

Any idea what I could add to it in order to have 23/04/2017 disabled as a choice ?

Thanks for your upcoming help guys !

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for something like this. Note the beforeShowDay 'filter' function, which for each date displayed in the calendar processes for a boolean true or false to display it as available or not. I've used an array for the dates you're checking against in case you need to test for more than one in the future.

```
gform.addFilter( 'gform_datepicker_options_pre_init', function( optionsObj, formId, fieldId ) {
    if ( formId == 2 && fieldId == 4 ) {
      optionsObj.minDate = '17/04/2017';
      optionsObj.maxDate = '29/04/2017';

      optionsObj.beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var array = ["2017-04-23"];
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ];
      }
    }

return optionsObj;
} );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer mate but this doesn't seem to cut it tho. Instead it's like it "cancels" the previous code and the whole thing is back to its standard setting (every date on the calendar can now be picked  : every day is back to being available, including past dates).

NB : my coding skills are very noobish, maybe I could have done something wrong but I honestly just copied your new code to paste it below the old one.

Comment: Do you happen to have a link you can share? Or failing that, are there any console javascript errors when you hit F11, go to the console tab?

Answer (score -1):

For removing the weekend days.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
gform.addFilter( 'gform_datepicker_options_pre_init', function( optionsObj, formId, fieldId ) {
  if ( (formId == 2 && fieldId == 4)) {
        optionsObj.firstDay = 1;
        optionsObj.minDate = 0;
        optionsObj.beforeShowDay = jQuery.datepicker.noWeekends;
        optionsObj.changeMonth = false;
        optionsObj.changeYear = false; 
  }
  return optionsObj;
  
 });
});
```

Comment: this only removes weekend days, which OP specifically does not want - they only want a single day removed.